# SyncLock on List in Multithread still throws ArgumentException

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, locking, synclock

I need to read from a list on a (background) thread while it may be updated from another (main thread). So I try to just make a temporary list not to access the original object. As updates may occur on multiple places, it would be convenient to place SyncLock on the read logic. Is that inherently wrong? What are my options for locking this correctly, or other ways to acquire an accessible copy of the list in a multithread condition?

```
 ' In Main thread: 
 Public SomeList = New List(Of SomeClass) 
 ' ..edit list


 ' In other thread: 
  Dim tempList As List(Of SomeClass)
  SyncLock SomeList
      tempList = SomeList.ToList
  End SyncLock
```

*SomeList.ToList* throws:

> ArgumentException, Destination array was not long enough. Check
>   destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing `.ToList` and thus `New List(Of SomeClass)(.)`, in Reflector, the exception must be coming from `is2.CopyTo(Me._items, 0)` where `Me._items` has just been set to `New T(count - 1) {}`.

This means the number of items in the input collection (cast to `ICollection(Of T)` in `is2`) must have increased after `is2.Count` was retrieved.

As such, I re-ask the assumption in my now deleted answer: Do all places in the Main thread, in `' ..edit list`, also use `SyncLock SomeList` when modifying the list?

Comment: You are correct, I was not properly educated on the use of SynckLock when asking this question, so it's now clear the list was modified by other thread without a lock, as you said. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the equivalent is in VB, but can't you do something like this?

```
IList<string> roDinosaurs = dinosaurs.AsReadOnly();
```

Or

```
tempList.AddRange(SomeList);
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this works, at least so far, but was looking to understand also why my use of synclock is faulty.

Comment: @bretddog I don't believe it is though.  Its the method that's throwing the error rather than the SyncLock, I don't think they are related.  (It certainly wouldn't be with C# and lock).